# Arduino Mini Pro 3.3 V Issue with Bluetooth Mate

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, arduino-pro-mini

I have an Arduino Mini Pro 3.3 V powered from a coin cell(3.6 V, CR2450) and connected to Bluetooth Mate Gold. I have checked the connections and they are fine. I can also connect to the bluetooth from while trying to upload the file and also from Android bluetooth terminal.I am not sure if it could be bootloader issue as I have checked 2 Arduino Mini Pros that give the same problem running the sample sketch on the bluetooth hookup guide.

- Arduino: 1.6.5 (Mac OS X)
- Board: "Arduino Pro or Pro Mini, ATmega328 (3.3V, 8 MHz)"

The error is:

```
Sketch uses 2,412 bytes (7%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30,720 bytes.
Global variables use 210 bytes (10%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1,838 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
```

I burned the bootloader again but no success.

I get the same with UNO. However with UNO, when I press the reboot button before the program uploads is works.

Could someone point me out to the solution to this? Thanks

Comment: How did you connect the arduino reset pin to the BT-module?

Comment: @Gerben I used this [hookup guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/using-the-bluesmirf?_ga=1.22302195.979952980.1432625509#hardware-hookup). For Pro-Mini the pins just match. Isn't it?

Comment: That guide doesn't connect the reset. So you have to manually reset the arduino just before programming.